# Change existing database entry from a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

snippets of my code (views and forms)

my views.py:

```
 def checkout(request):
    print "signup"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "post payment"
        form = PaymentForm(request.POST)
        try:
            if form.is_valid():
                print form.cleaned_data
                ui.balance = ui.balance - (form.cleaned_data['amount'] * form.cleaned_data['price'])
                u.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                u.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                u.save()
                print "after login in signup"
                return redirect("/student/control")


            else:
                print "error"
                print form.errors
        except:
            raise
            print "error here"
            print form.errors
            pass
            #return render(request, 'student/register.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        form = PaymentForm()

    return render(request, 'student/control.html', {'form': form})
```

and my forms.py:

```
 class PaymentForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 25)
    last_name = forms.CharField( max_length = 25)
    amount = forms.IntegerField()
    price = forms.FloatField()
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PaymentForm, self).clean()

        if User.objects.filter(first_name != cleaned_data['first_name']).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError({'first_name':['Name does not exist']})
        if User.objects.filter(last_name != cleaned_data['last_name']).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError({'last_name':['Name does not exist']})

        return cleaned_data
```

This problem hasn't happened before, as
I used this same format for a register page and its working fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you importing PaymentForm in your views.py ?

Comment: no, from forms.py @Gocht

Comment: Yes, I know `PaymentForm` lives in `forms.py` but you need to call it in `views.py` -> `from somewhere.forms import PaymentForm`

Comment: ...I'm such an idiot @Gocht

Comment: Don't say that, I am posting this as an answer, becase is a very common problem.

Comment: Dude I think you can not change your question like this, because now previous answer are not valid, you need to post a new question. I will be waiting for a new (and more explicit) question.

Comment: ok sorry, i just didnt want to wait 90 minutes to ask again @Gocht

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93931/discussion-between-abhishek-patel-and-gocht).

Comment: Chat room does not allow me write because the time as gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that you need to import a class to be able to use it.

In this case, you need to use `PaymentForm` from `forms.py` in your `views.py`. So you need to do the import:

```
# views.py
from somewhere.forms import PaymentForm
```

Now, you can use `PaymentForm` in `views.py`